# How to use the wordpress next gen gallery plugin stuff in front end

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gallery

I have used next gen gallery in my word press project,I just wanted to have the next gen gallery functionality  in the front end so user can upload multiple images and tags them from front end.any one have suggestion on this one?

Comment: This cannot be done from the front end without massive rewriting of the plugin. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using short codes just visit plugin [faq page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/faq/).and also you can use the next gen widgets to display